# How to improve time performance for retrieving huge data from the database?

Tags: performance, time, sqlite

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     AppDelegate *appDelegate =  (AppDelegate *) [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     List = [appDelegate getList];
}
```

Here getList is a method that gets the 29000 number of list from the sqlite3 database.I am getting the list but it takes very huge time to respond in the device. Is there any other way to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What end-user is going to scroll or need access to all 29,000 entries in one go?

You must be able to use paging in sqlite3. In SQLite you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000
```

Which would return 1000 rows starting from row 2000.

Comment: I want 29000 entries in one go